# Delete some text file from Sever after a period of time

Tags: php, file

I am developing a online store. There is no sign up option. So i used Ajax and PHP to keep users wishlists and carts. For that i create some text file on the server.

Is that okay, or there is better way to do that?

Second question is; if I want to delete those text files after a certain period of time automatically, is it possible?

Comment: Hint: [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: **OMG** are you serious?

Comment: You may want to protect those text files with Apache's `.htaccess` should they contain vital information. What kind of text files are we dealing with here? Btw, that isn't my downvote in there. I think you would be better off using a database really.

Comment: text files contain only the product list, their price,quantity and total price that user selects to buy.I want to delete them in every 24 hrs.

Comment: you can use date/time-related functions and `unlink()` to delete files, and possibly cron.

Comment: is that a better way to keep user data temporarily in server?

Comment: your question is too broad. You've been given an answer below on how to proceed; it's a start.

Comment: can u please take a look at this.
http://nsu.honor.es/

Answer (score 1):

For storing information you might want to lookup MySQL or other type of database.

For dealing with information expiry date you can do two things:

1. While storing new information to the database, add a `added_on` field with current datetime. Upon retrieval, check if that date is older than required period of time and use it accordingly.
2. Another way is to also store the `added_on` date and use CRON jobs to check once in a while if that entry is older than required period of time and if it is, delete it.